# conditional breakpoints with c++ in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, conditional-statements, breakpoints

Is it possible to have conditional breakpoints (without changing anything about the sourcecode) in Vistual Studio 2008 with C++ language?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can specify a [condition on a breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) in any language. Note that this can slow execution down quite a bit, depending on the condition and how often the check has to be made.