# visual studio breaking point condition: trigger break when something returns false. Is it possible

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, optimization, triggers, conditional-breakpoint

I have a function body that contains many other functions calls that may in some moment of time returns false. It is very boring to place each breakpoint at the row, because the points are so many every time. It's about Visual Studio 2008. Is there any way to set some breaking condition: ex: "When something returns false in that body - break and wait until F10 or whatever." ? I will be very glad if you know something about it.. or may be good plugin for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [conditional breakpoints with c++ in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068114/conditional-breakpoints-with-c-in-visual-studio)

Comment: it is not the same, anybody know how to test for 'return false' from one of the functions that I call ?